# Multipliers and corners of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^*$-algebras. Suppose that there exists a projection $p$ in $\mathcal{M}(B)$, the multiplier algebra of $B$, such that $A=pBp$. That is, $A$ is a corner of $B$.

**Question:** Is it true that the corner $p(\mathcal{M}(B))p$ contains the multiplier algebra of $A$ (which we view as a subalgebra of $B$)? In other words, does every multiplier of the corner come from the corner of the multiplier algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Yes. We have
$$
 M(A) = M(pBp) = pBp \subseteq pM(B)p.
$$
The second equality holds since $pBp$ is a unital C*-algebra.</strike>

Corrected version: There is an obvious map $\iota \colon pBp \hookrightarrow  p M(B)p$. This inclusion extends to the multiplieralgebra $\bar \iota \colon M(pBp) \to pM(B)p$. The extension exists since $\iota$ is non-degenerate. Indeed, if $(e_n)$ is an approximate unit for $B$, then $pe_np \to p$ strictly, which is the unit of $pM(B)p$. Furthermore, it is clear that  $\bar \iota$ is still injective.

Comment: Why must $pBp$ be unital if we start off with $B$ non-unital?

Comment: Ah okay, I made a mistake. It is not the case that that $pBp$ is strictly closed in $M(B)$, e.g. $ \mathbb K = 1_{B(H)} \mathbb K 1_{B(H)}$.

Comment: I have corrected the proof. Thanks for pointing out.